# How can i create this crease detail on glass?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

I've been using blender for over 6 months now. I'm doing this rum bottle and I don't know how to make the detail in the glass.

[image]

When i try, i get this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/bas-relief-model-from-a-3d-model-scene https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150639/how-can-i-write-something-on-an-object/150656#150656~https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder